# Getting invalid ELF header issue

Tags: node.js, npm

When i am trying to install the npm getting this followed issue....

```
module.js:485
  process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);
          ^
Error: /projects/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/projects/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

any one can help how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess uou are trying to run binaries compiled for another platform, or processor architecture.

Comment: right now i have a ember project for that need to install npm when i was trying to use npm install getting Elf header issue.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what your problem is.  Do you have a problem **installing npm**, or a problem using **npm install**???

Comment: yes getting an error when instaling npm

Comment: It seem that problem lays in module source code. Try to check what arguments of macro `NODE_MODULE` corresponds to module name.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess: you installed it on your local machine, then tried to run it on your whichever VM. Try uninstalling it and then installing it on your vagrant locally.